# Force redirect http to https on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In order to redirect http to https on a AWS Elastic Beanstalk php application i'm using rewrite rules on .htaccess file.

My problem is that my rules work fine for urls pointing to files but not for the root domain, for example:

```
http://www.testdomain.com/index.php => redirects OK to => https://www.testdomain.com/index.php
```

but

```
http://www.testdomain.com  does not redirect to https://www.testdomain.com
```

My Rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/status$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/version$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/ 
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) `.` expects at least one character. If you want to match any, including an empty, URL path use either `^` or `^.*$`

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

You can also use [`%{HTTPS}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to test for a SSL connection

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```